# Selecting Window in selenium without using title

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-rc

For my webapp, I need to open gmail account and take up a randomly generated string password from mail and copy it on my portal.
The problem is I login in my webapp using gmail account. So when I open gmail in another window Its session is already up and directly inbox page opens and I am not able to shift focus to this page as its title is dynamic as in "Inbox (38) - demo@miniorange.co.in - MiniOrange Mail" depending on pending messages.

I need a way to select my window without using its title.

Answer (score 4):

This has been discussed many times; do not try to automate gmail or any other web browser unless you work for the email company!

It is inherently unstable and far better to use the email API if you need to check an email has been sent, validate content or extract data to continue a flow.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/selenium-users/8jR6Fw5ndxU/7peVDuzkNN4J

Comment: I am kinda new to this. Could you give me some instructions for a proper and robust way to extract information from an email ?

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work with any number of popus

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String handle = iterator.next();
    if (!handle.contains(parentWindow)) {
        // Switch to popup 
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        // Do something          
    }
}
// Switch back to parentWindow
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```